# RabbitMq: Setup TLS with Intermediate Wildcard Certifcate

Tags: ssl, openssl, erlang, rabbitmq, tls1.2

I am using latest RabbitMq 3.5.6 with Erlang 18.1 on Ubuntu.

I want to secure communication with TLS. So I bought a wildcard certificate (AlphaSSL) which comes with an Intermediate cert chain.

(Removed Certs)

I am using the same certificate to secure Nginx and Apache2. The cert works there.

But in RabbitMq, I dont know how to get it working properly. At some stage of my testing, I had "Verfiy Ok" when testing with `openssl -sclient`... Then switched to browser, but management Interface doesn't even load: SSL_SEC_ERR in Chrome...

This is the config of the management section:

**UPDATE:** This config works. After doing `apt-get install erlang-ssl --reinstall` it suddenly works as expected. Make sure to use latest Erlang 18.1 Version from http://erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp which contains some TLS related fixes

rabbitmq.config:

```
{rabbitmq_management,
   {listener, [{port,     15672},
                {ssl,      true},
                {ssl_opts, [{cacertfile, "/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/Intermediate_CA_Bundle.crt"},
                            {certfile,   "/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/domain.crt"},
                            {keyfile,    "/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/domain.key"},
                            {depth, 2},
                            {verify, verify_none},
                            {fail_if_no_peer_cert, false}]}]}
```

mablae

Comment: It seems, this configuration is just right. After doing `apt-get install erlang-ssl --reinstall` it suddenly works as expected. Make sure to use latest Erlang 18.1 Version from https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp which contains some TLS related fixes

Comment: I really hope that isn't actually your private key you just posted on the internet.

Comment: It isnt ;-) Just for the format of the file... I replaced many chars from the original

Comment: I don't want to scare you, but generally the obfuscation method you describe is not safe, so I have analysed your private key, as published, and I think you may have severely compromised it. One of the primes is intact and though you may want to take advice from a specialist, I am fairly suspicious that someone could construct a brute force algorithm to reconstruct the key or a set of likely keys to try, with the computational resources of an iphone. If the security of this key is important to you please consider this possibility.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I considered sth like this would be possible with some efforts.. Will do better next time. Maybe I just revoke the cert to be safe even if the cert is not in use in public network.

Comment: If the security is at all important I believe you must revoke the certificate yes, and any other certificates created from this key, and throw the key away obviously.

Comment: Yeah. Sure. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @mblaettermann what should the host name of the machine if we use wildcart certificate ? For example if I use *.example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This config works. After doing `apt-get install erlang-ssl --reinstall` it suddenly works as expected. Make sure to use latest Erlang 18.1 Version from http://erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp which contains some TLS related fixes